# Zabbix item timestamps

Tags: logging, zabbix

Facing trouble with trigger depending on two log items.

We have one logfile and two items that are taken from it:
logrt[/../../logfile.log,"Start exchange"]
logrt[/../../logfile.log,"Finish exchange"]

Also have trigger, that is raised, when "Started exchange" message is received, and "Finished exchange" message is not received.
And everything goes fine, but sometimes item "Start exchange" is received later than "finish exchange" (in log file they are sequential, but zabbix takes "Finish exchange" first, and "Start exchange" second) so, there is a question: is there any way to compare item timestamps without using scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are feature requests to access value timestamps like https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2045 , in general it is not easily doable currently.

There might be a solution, but you'd need to show how the values are exchanged in time, and what your trigger configuration is like.